# Index of directory being shown rather than an application being run when trying to configure Shiny

Tags: apache-2.4

I cannot seem to correctly configure Shiny on my Apache 2.4 server. I have used an Alias to direct `/shiny/` to `/srv/shiny-server/` so going to `myserver/shiny/` shows the "Welcome to Shiny Server!" page (`index.html`) as it should.

However, on this page, there is a panel on the right-hand side, which is captioned below with -

> When Shiny is properly configured on your server, you'll see a Shiny app above.

Instead of showing a Shiny app, it is displaying the Index of /shiny/sample-apps/hello (with Name, Last Modified, Size, and Description) *(Apologies, I would have included an image of this but cannot do so without the prerequisite reputation)*

I have spent some time reading the [Admin Guide](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/) as suggested, and looked at [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22302463/3580568), however I am none the wiser.

- Is there anything obvious which may be the cause of this type of error?
- Is there any other information I can provide which may be helpful?

My apologies, I am quite new to Linux, Apache, and Shiny, so this is all a bit of an uphill struggle.